# 3D Rotate using perspective in JQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was going to answer a question tagged JQuery which got closed(off-topic).I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/175/) to answer it. It is working just as I wanted it to, but the rotated divs do not look as I wanted them to.

**It looks like >**

[image]

**Instead of this >**

[image]

I am using `perspective` and `rotateY` for the rotate effect I have achieved till now. I just need help in CSS for this.

Comment: i think same question
[css3-transform][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293736/css3-transform-skew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the `transform-origin` point, try this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
```

See this fiddle:
The demo http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/185/

Comment: Thaks @Zword for edit the fiddle to make both work i was without time to make the full answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Your containers are not large enough for the perspective'd and rotated div. Consequently it gets chopped off. (Margins are also needed on the content-container to scoot them down)

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
width: auto;
margin-top:40px;
height: 600px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
perspective: 800px;
-moz-perspective: 800px;
-webkit-perspective: 800px;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fgM49/

Comment: But i need the divs to look like as i showed it in the question(after instead of)

Comment: then fix your perspective origin. The other guy was completely right and you needlessly disregarded it.

Comment: As i told in the comment below that answer it solves the problem for left div only

Answer (score 2):

for left div

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(30deg);
```

for right div

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-30deg);
```

for crossbrowser support you can use http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

```
$('').transition({
  perspective: '100px',
  rotateY: '30deg'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add scaleY(0.94) like

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) rotateY(30deg);
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/190/

Comment: Your answer is also good.+1 for that. But I like more the accepted answer fiddle.